# How to number format only certain cells that contain data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code reads lines from a csv file and reformats row headings.  I hope I can articulate this, but I'd like to format cells to two decimals in rows below headings in which the `vct_FEMAP_Results()` function returns a value.

---

**Example:**

```
   ID    "CSys ID"   "Set ID"     Plate Top VM Stress     Plate Bot VM Stress  
 ------ ----------- ---------- ----------------------- ---------------------- 
  4591         0         20              229.9488               244.8103  
  4592         0         20              323.5026               315.1129
```

I'm trying to format the cells containing the decimals without affecting the data in column headings `ID`, `CSys ID`, or `Set ID`.  The code below formats all columns to **2 decimals**.  Not sure why.

```
Sub cmdOpen_Click()
    Dim wrdArray() As String, txtstrm As TextStream, line As String
    Dim wrd As Variant, myWrd As String
    Dim col As Long, colCount As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim row As Long, temp As Long

    Dim str As String, regex As RegExp
    Dim matches As MatchCollection, lineMatch As match, wrdMatch As match
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    Dim strPath As String, strLine As String

    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "\d+"
    regex.Global = True

    'Remove Filters and Add Custom Filters
    Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
    Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("Text Files", "*.txt")
    Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("Dat Files", "*.dat")
    Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("Comma Delimited Files", "*.csv")

    'only allow the user to select one file
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    End If
'------------------------------------------------------------

     If strPath <> "" Then
        Set txtstrm = FSO.OpenTextFile(strPath)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    row = 1
    Do Until txtstrm.AtEndOfStream
      line = txtstrm.ReadLine

      x = 1
      col = 1
      count = 0

      wrdArray() = Split(line, ",")

      For Each wrd In wrdArray()
        count = count + 1
        myWrd = wrd

        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = wrd
        col = col + 1
      Next wrd

      If (row = 1) Then
        For i = 0 To count - 1
            Set matches = regex.Execute(wrdArray(i))
            For Each wrdMatch In matches
                If wrdMatch Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = vct_FEMAP_Results(wrdMatch.Value)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next i
      End If

    row = row + 1
    Loop

    txtstrm.Close

    For i = 1 To row - 1
        For j = x To col - 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: My attempt at drawing an excel spreadsheet got hosed.  If you can't decipher, maybe I could upload a bmp.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  (Please no data in image-form!_) One way to create a table is to copy & paste from your spreadsheet app into the [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). (set "Output Style" to `ASCII Compact`), copy the rendered table and paste into your question.  Them highlight that and hit CTRL+G

Comment: Hopefully the edited version above is decipherable.  Thanks!

Comment: Much easier to read! :-)   ...but I'm curious why you're opening the `.csv` cell-by-cell like this instead of doing it with a built-in method, perhaps a single line of code with [the `Workbooks.OpenText` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel).  Also you can apply number formatting to the column programmatically or manually, but it's going to be gone as soon as you close the file, **since `CSV` files do not store formatting** of any kind. `CSV` (Comma-separated values) files are nothing more that a text file with comma's between values.

Comment: It's a little complicated (at least to me) because the FEMAP output vectors look something like this: "7021..Plate Top Y Normal Stress".  The number 7021 is the FEMAP output vector which always corresponds to "Plate Top Y Normal Stress". So I first find the vector number and call a function to find the output vector title and then populate the spreadsheet with the data.  Ultimately I'd like to be able to manipulate which column each data set is written.  I was doing this all manually (repeatedly) and was trying to make life easier.  :)

Comment: P.S. I didn't know about the Workbooks.OpenText method so I will definitely look into that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is formatting all your columns because you are looping through the columns with this bit:

```
For i = 1 To row - 1
    For j = x To col - 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Next j
Next i
```

If you already know which columns need to be formatted, just do it like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("d:d, e:e").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

That will reformat only columns D and E, as per your sample data. Change the d's and e's if you need other columns.

I actually prefer to avoid using "ActiveSheet" and always reference the specific worksheet explicitly, so I'm always sure which worksheet my code is targeting. Whereas, when you use ActiveSheet(or cell or workbook) the active sheet can change, sometimes in unexpected ways.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("d:d, e:e").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The issue is that the columns that require formatting will depend on the FEMAP output selected.  I'd like to be able to dynamically set the range to format depending on the data file.  By setting the range on j from "x to col - 1" I thought the formatting would begin at the column of interest.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I realize the error.  I was using "x" as the start but "x" get reassigned to 1 each time through the loop and the reassignment occurs inside the do loop.  Easy to fix!  Thank you.